# Matlab script taking too long

Tags: performance, matlab

I am trying to run on a 4GB, 2.4 GHz Windows 10 laptop a Matlab program written by a colleague and it really takes too long, I typically interrupt it after 5 minutes of unresponsive running.

I ran the profiler and noticed that symbolic functions runtime was killing me. At one point, a couple dozen polynomials are defined this way and the program slows significantly at these definitions:

```
syms P11 x y; P11= (x/r).*(y/r).*(((x/r).^2+(y/r).^2)-3);
```

Is there a way to possibly gain speed while using these polynomials? The computer specs may be low but it does not seem to be struggling, i.e. processors are running at 12%, RAM at 67%, disk usage nothing. On another computer with a slightly faster processor, the same program takes 130s on Matlab 2012.

Comment: Is there a reason to use symbolic math? Symbolic math is known to be slow because there is no native support by the hardware. There is no magic "make the code faster switch", please give a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Regarding the different performance on another system: Same matlab version?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention it was Matlab 2012 on the other computer, and I have every reason to believe that the program was made using that version of the software.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to replace such symbolic variables with anonymous functions (or by using `inline` in older Matlab versions, function that now is deprecated):

```
P11=@(x,y,r) (x/r).*(y/r).*(((x/r).^2+(y/r).^2)-3);
```

In this manner you work with double variables only since `x`,`y` and `r` are now double and not symbolic. `P11` will be a function handle and you can gather the result of such formula by simply calling:

```
myResult=P11(myX,myY,myR);
```

where `myX`,`myY`,`myR` are your values for `x`,`y`,`r`.

Comment: Inline and anonymous functions are something else. Compare [`inline`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html) and [Anonymous Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).  You where right to use a anonymous function in your answer, never use `inline`.

Comment: Yes, sorry Daniel. Saying *also known as* might be misleading. What I really meant is that you can achieve the same results by using `inline` and Anonymous Functions: indeed the anonymous function above can be re-written as `P11=inline('(x/r).*(y/r).*(((x/r).^2+(y/r).^2)-3)','x','y','r')` and called as `P11(myX,myY,myR)` as well.

Comment: I think there is no reason to bother with `inline` at all. Anonymous functions have been introduced more than 10 years ago in Matlab 7.0.

Comment: `inline` is deprecated and slow.